# JavaScript Profiler like JetBrains dotTrace?

Tags: javascript, profiler, dottrace

I'm a big fan of dotTrace for my web application and I wanted to find a solid javascript profiler that functions about the same way.  I've looked around and can't seem to find a JavaScript profiler like that.

Anyone know of a Javascript profiler like dotTrace?

Comment: Like dotTrace in what way(s)? Can you list the features you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Javascript profiler is included with IE8: http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx . It has reports and output that look somewhat like dotTrace.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has a decent profiler built in, plus lots of other useful stuff. Please be more specific if there are particular features you're after.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for Firebug called [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) that I would recommend if you're looking for performance improvements.

Also, the Venkman debugger [offers](http://www.hacksrus.com/~ginda/venkman/faq/venkman-faq.html#profiler) profiling. Here's the [latest version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216).

Answer (score 0):

There is always the Firefox plug-in called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/js.html).